# Detecting arrival of push notification with Trigger.io

Tags: android, push-notification, trigger.io

I'm building an android app with trigger.io. When a push notification is received while the app is in the foreground, I need to detect this in order to update information in the app.

As far as I can tell, the documentation says this is possible, via the messagePushed event. As per the documentation, this event is "triggered when a push notification is received both while the application is running or if the application is launched via that notification."

However, in my testing this even ONLY fires when the application is launched via the notification. The event does NOT fire if the app is in the foreground. (I am using the standard way to detect this event with "forge.event.messagePushed.addListener")

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong, or misunderstand the documentation, or if this is a bug in trigger.io?

Comment: I have not tested the in app push but have you checked to see if your event listener is being called from inside the app while it running? 

If it is I would assume you could call the function once a push notification is recieved.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, user1717573. Not sure if I understand your suggestion: The problem is that I can find no way to tell when a push notification is received, because the messagePushed event is never triggered by the trigger.io toolkit. (again, it works fine when launched via a notification, but in order for push notifications to be useful for most apps they also need to be detectable if they arrive while the app is running.)

Comment: Sorry for not be clear on what I was saying :) I was trying to say that in your listener callback do you have any alerts or console.logs to see if it is getting fired or if its throwing and error etc?

Comment: Thanks again- If I set an alert it does NOT fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the receipt behaviour on Android and iOS was actually a symptom of the Parse SDK - it used to be you could only specify an Activity (in our case, your app) to be opened when the user goes to select the system tray notification.

In more recent Parse SDKs, they've added to this so that an app can be notified of inbound pushes at receipt time.

We've haven't updated our API and Parse module to support that yet. I'll open a ticket and report back here when that change is available in a new platform version